# Joomla intro image with hover-overlay and showing intro text

Tags: php, css, joomla

I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

**Goal...**
When in a Joomla *content blog view* I show an intro image, I want, on hover, to fade it to 20% and show the intro text, in black, on top of the intro image.

**What I've done so far...**
Alter the Joomla core file *blog_item.php* from

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo '<div id="box">'; ?>
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.intro_image', $this->item); ?>
    <?php echo '<div id="overlay">'; ?>
        <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
    <?php echo '</div>'; ?>
<?php echo '</div>'; ?>
```

and added CSS for opacity and positioning.

**The problem is...** The *div overlay* hovers over the introduction-image-link. So it's no longer clickable.

**My question...** How can I give the *div overlay* the same href as the introduction-image?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I can think of right away is to implement a click listener on the overlay div and take the user to the desired url using `window.location`